# Informatica Cloud- Null character issue in from dat file

Tags: informatica-cloud

I am getting the following task error in Informatica Cloud.

```
FR_3085 ERROR: Row [1]: 2-th character is a null character, which is not allowed in a text input file d:\temp\psaas.csv.
```

How to fix this issue, I tried to use ReplaceStr(0, input, char(10), '') in the filter condition, but its still throwing me an error?

thanks
Bhavesh

Answer (score 1):

What character set do you have set for the connector? You may need to set it to windows character or make sure your file is using UTF-8. Attaching the source file may help to understand the issue.

Comment: I found out characters like * and null characters. I have used this expression (ReplaceStr(0,Input,Char(10),' ')), which didn't help me

Comment: FYI..It is a .dat file

Comment: The error is on the source file as a source. An expression will not fix it, the source file must be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your input file contains some invalid characters.
You can fix this issue by changing the file encoding.
Try to change the file encoding to "UTF-8" or "ANSI". Save the file and restart the job.